# Custom 500 error page in Hybris

Tags: spring-mvc, error-handling, web.xml, sap-commerce-cloud, http-status-code-500

I have to redirect the 500 error page you see in the picture on an empty page in Hybris.

[image]

How can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried enabling error-page in web.xml ?

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement custom error pages to prevent such unexpected behavior. Mosty it handled at Apache Web Server. Like [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html), [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04).

However, as @Free-Minded answered, you can also configure in Hybris using **error-page** tag of yourstorefront's **web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>java.lang.Exception</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```